# Virtual void, classes, constructors, polymorphism - order of execution

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism, virtual

I have problem with understanding order of execution in virtual void/polymorphism based program.

As far as I understand what happens in other outputs, I have no idea why those commands:

```
a->b();
d->b();
d->a();
((G*)d) -> a();
```

give following outputs:

```
Nieznany
Nieznany
Gniewosz
```

Could anyone please explain me why those 3 methods print results as above?

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std; 

    class C { public:
    C() {cout << "Buduje A";}
    void a() {cout << "Nauczyciel" << endl;}
    virtual ~C() {cout << "~D" << endl;}
    virtual void b() {cout << "Nieznany" << endl; }; };

class G {
    int e; public:
    G() {cout << "Buduje G ";}
    void a() {cout << "Gniewosz " << endl;}
    ~G() {cout << "~C " << endl; }
    void b() {cout << "Draka" << endl;}; };

class A :public C {
    int o;
    int a;

public:
    A() {cout << "Buduje C ";}
    ~A() {cout << "~F " << endl;} };

class D :public A {
    float f; public:
    D() {cout << "Buduje D";}
    virtual void a() {cout << "Pośrednik" << endl;}
    ~D() {cout << "~E" << endl;} };

class B :public D {
    short s;
    int b; public:
    B() {cout << "Buduje E ";}
    ~B() {cout << "~G" << endl;} };

class E :public B {
    E() {cout << "Buduje B";}
    ~E() {cout << "~I" << endl;} };

class F :public G, public D { public:
    F() {cout << "Buduje F ";}
    void a() {cout << "Nieznany " << endl;}
    void b() {}
    ~F() {cout << "~H" << endl;} };

void nic() {cout << endl;}

int main() {
    C*a = new B();
    nic();
    a->b();
    D*d = new F;
    nic();
    d->b();
    d->a();
    ((G*)d) -> a();
    delete d;
    delete a;

    return 0; }
```

Comment: What did you observe stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: when calling constructor, output is written off from a class that does not inherit from any other. deconstructor's output starts from a class that is called

Comment: Could you please explain to us why those 3 methods shouldn't print the results as above? What would you expect?

Comment: These type of "follow through the inheritance maze" questions are non-productive IMO.  As long as you know what `virtual` means, that virtual dispatch functions is not invoked during construction, `virtual destructor`, static and dynamic object creation, etc. shouldn't that be enough?  I would just fire up the debugger ...